# Eliminar archivos de directorio en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

necesito su apoyo.
Estoy haciendo un proyecto en laravel y voy sacando fragmentos de algunos videos para poder eliminar una imagen de mi directorio. Pero solo logro borrarla de la base y se queda en el directorio

```
public function destroy($id)
        {
            $Imagen = Sucursal::find($id,'Imagen');
            $datos = str_replace('storage','sucursales', $Imagen);
            
            Storage::delete($datos);
            $sucursal = Sucursal::find($id)->delete();
            return redirect()->route('sucursal.index')->withSuccess('Se eliminó correctamente!');
        }
```

Si imprimo "$datos" me imprime esto
{"Imagen":"sucursales/1704301971-D_NQ_NP_2X_917818-MLM69201573584_052023-F.jpeg"}

Agradezco su apoyo

Answer (score 0):

Para eliminar un archivo del directorio en Laravel, debes asegurarte de que estás proporcionando la ruta correcta al método `Storage::delete()`. En tu caso, parece que estás obteniendo la ruta del campo Imagen de un modelo Sucursal. Sin embargo, es posible que necesites acceder directamente al valor de este campo en lugar de al objeto completo.

Ejemplo de como lo haria yo:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    // Obtén la Sucursal por su ID
    $sucursal = Sucursal::find($id);

    // Verifica si la Sucursal existe
    if ($sucursal) {
        // Obten la ruta de la imagen desde el campo 'Imagen'
        $rutaImagen = $sucursal->Imagen;

        // Reemplaza 'storage' con 'sucursales' en la ruta
        $rutaImagen = str_replace('storage', 'sucursales', $rutaImagen);

        // Elimina el archivo del directorio
        Storage::delete($rutaImagen);

        // Elimina la Sucursal de la base de datos
        $sucursal->delete();

        // Redirige con un mensaje de éxito
        return redirect()->route('sucursal.index')->withSuccess('Se eliminó correctamente!');
    } else {
        // Manejar el caso en que la Sucursal no se encuentra
        return redirect()->route('sucursal.index')->with('error', 'La sucursal no se encontró.');
    }
}
```

Comment: la ruta donde se guardan las imagenes es public/sucursales/ pero no se borran. es la misma ruta que cuardo en el registro de la base de datos

Comment: el usuario que ejecuta tu php tiene permisos para hacer ese borrado puedes revisar el log de actividad para verificar por que no se borra o evaluar si se borro el archivo en tiempo real ... tambien el validar si el archivo existe como lo indique en mi respuesta

Comment: Prueba con `Storage::delete("public/{$sucursal->Imagen}")` o `Storage::disk('public')->delete($sucursal->Imagen)`

Answer (score 0):

Te voy a proporcionar un ejemplo:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        // Encuentra la sucursal por su ID
        $sucursal = Sucursal::find($id);
        
        // Si no existe la sucursal, se envíe un mensaje de error.
        if (!$sucursal) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Sucursal no encontrada.');
        }
        
        //le paso el nombre de la imagen con su extensión. Ejemplo: imagen.jpg y esto se lo paso a la variable $filename
        $filename = $sucursal->imagen;

        //obtenemos la ruta completa ejemplo: public/sucursales/imagen.jpg
        $path = public_path('sucursales/' . $filename);

        // Verifica si el archivo existe y elimínalo
        if (File::exists($path)) {
            File::delete($path);
        }

        // Actualiza el registro de la sucursal
        $sucursal->imagen = null;
        $sucursal->save();

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Imagen eliminada con éxito.');
    }
```

Saludos y Dios le bendiga.